# Symfony 2 Forms one to many without collection (only add one item)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections

I'm building a simple form having a `one-to-many` relation from an `User` entity :

`User 1..* actions`

So basically, in my user form, i have to set the `actions` property to the `collection` form type.

I don't want the client to be able to add multiple actions within the form, but only one when editing the user.

The problem is that Symfony 2 form expect to get all the actions from the form on `submit`, so existing actions are removed from database on flush and only the new one remain.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your entity `User` has an array of `Action`s, and you create a form type `UserType` with `data_class => User`, Symfony expects you to add to that form a `collection` field for actions, because that's what the entity has.

That's the way Symfony works. Personally I don't like this tight coupling between entities in the model and forms, but it works pretty well for simple apps.

If you want to have a form type that does not match any entity, things won't be so simple, but you'll have more control of things.
You have some options (as far as I know, maybe there're other):

1. You can move to a task-based UI, by creating another class that represents the data you need to perform an action - in your case you want to edit an user, so you can create a `EditUserCommand`, which contains 1 and only 1 `Action`, as long as other fields, most of them probably exactly the same as your `User` class.
   Now you can map your form to this `EditUserCommand` class, which will contain only 1 action as you want. Obviously later you need to use this command class to get the data you need to edit the user.
2. Use the [`empty_data` option with a closure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/use_empty_data.html#option-2-provide-a-closure) that receives the submitted `FormInterface`, so that you can get the submitted data from there and use it as you want to update the user.

In both options you're breaking the coupling between your `User` class and your `EditUserType` form, which means you need to do some more work, but imo it has many benefits.
You can find further reading on this subject [here](http://verraes.net/2013/04/decoupling-symfony2-forms-from-entities/).